# How to render json with pretty print when in dev mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My action has:

```
render json: {
   "user" : @user,
    "blah" : @blah
}
```

In dev mode, ie. Rails.env.development? is true I want to render the json using pretty print.

How can I do this?

Comment: if i understand it correctly, you can use chrome/firefox extension **JSON Formatter**. or just `render plain: JSON.pretty_generate(@user.as_json)`

Answer (score 2):

```
if Rails.env.development?
  render text: JSON.pretty_generate('user' => @user.attributes)
else
  render json: { 'user' => @user.attributes }
end
```

Comment: I am passing a hash, see above.  How can I do it in development mode only also?

Comment: @Blankman, see the revised variation. Development mode should not affect this.

Comment: I ONLY want pretty print when in dev mode, I think I have not understood my question :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@data.as_json)
```